# Custom login form in Magento, redirecting back to some customers

Tags: session, magento, authentication, magento-1.7

I have created a custom login form for an app created in Magento some time ago. Everything worked fine until now. Some of the customers are redirected back to the login form after the login process - **on their browsers** (if I try to login with their credentials, it's working fine).

So, my guess was sessions and I logged them. Session got it in the correct way.

Login is simple, based on Magento login form:

```
   if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
    $session = $this->_getSession();
    /* do some password stuff */
    // here here
    $session->login($login['username'], $client_password);
    $this->_loginPostRedirect();
```

I tested their login and logged the session: `Mage_Customer_Model_Session Object` - everything OK, looks the same as any other customer sessions.

The last url var for this kind of users is `/customer/account/loginPost/`.

I repeat: For some customers everything works OK. Also, for the users with problems, I can login myself into the app. What could happen? I saved the sessions in files and then I saved them in db - same results.

Comment: It can happen if exception is thrown before redirecting OR you can check the $client_password or whatever stuff you are doing on it, there could be a problem there

Comment: User & pass works ok. It just happened without doing anything on the code for at lease a month. It's defo a Cookie thing. No exceptions are thrown before.

Comment: ok so probably cache. is this browser specific? Can you try log in from another browser or have you tried deleting the user sessions saved and forcing the user to login again

Comment: I'm trying from different browsers and ips and everything is working fine. I cannot check on user's browser right now but I can see a lot of users stuck on the login (I check them in ONLINE CUSTOMERS from admin). Yes, I deleted the user sessions.

Comment: Alright, you can update your custom login code to delete the frontend cookie for a user on getting to the sign-in page. After login a new Frontend cookie will be created. You might just need to keep track if you have deleted for a user or not, by maybe setting another cookie after you delete it. 
If I may ask, how do you know users are stucked at Login? are you recording user interactions on your site?

Comment: How could I do that? Delete user's cookie? I check them in ONLINE CUSTOMERS and I see that they get stucked in this `/loginPost` (from `AccountController.php`) . Normal users have different `Last Url` value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161023/discussion-between-hardayborlar-and-tudor-radu-barbu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after days of hard check on Magento, I found the solution.

For Magento 1.7 (and older versions too) the problem comes from user sessions.

Copy the file `app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Session.php` to your local folder `app\code\local\Mage\Customer\Model\Session.php`.

Search for `public function login($username, $password)` and comment the line `$this->renewSession();`.

Magento can create a SESSION ID for the unsecure domain and another cookie for the secured domain. After that it can mess up when you click browser's `Back` button - redirecting you to the login page because it cannot find the correct SESSION ID created at login.